# Table borders not showing up in outlook desktop app but is visible in gmail and outlook when opened through browser

Tags: python, html, outlook, prettytable

I need to send data to users in the form of table in a presentable format.
I have the code which does it but unable to find why it doesnt show up on outlook desktop app. How can I work on it to ensure it works on outlook app as well?

I have already tried using hex code and colors like black grey red nothing worked.

```py
table1.get_html_string(attributes={”border-top”:”2px solid #000000"})
print(table1)
```

```html
<table frame="box" rules="all" border-top="2px solid #000000">
    <tr>
```

This table when sent over mail prints in table format but skips borders, only over Outlook Desktop App.Works fine over gmail and outlook when opened through browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-top` works just fine in Outlook. Your css is not valid. Try this instead:

```
<table style="border-top: 2px solid #000000;">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Comment: This worked thanks much. I am not getting borders for table rows and columns. I am fetching the table from my excel sheet into a prettytable object and used table1.get_html_string(attributes={”style”:”border:2px solid #000000"}) method here how to specify the style for row <tr> tag as the attribute is appending to <table> tag

Comment: You didn't ask for a border around each cell, you asked for a border around a table. If you want borders for all cells, try `<table border="1">`. For the top of specific `td` cells, apply `style="border-top: 2px solid #000000;"` to each cell.

Comment: Yes I understand I have to apply to each cell but I am not creating a html page manually. table1.get_html_string(attributes={”style”:”border:2px solid #000000"})  this method is fetching the data from table1 and printing in table format but the attributes are applying to the table, how can I apply it to cells throught this method?

Comment: @mithraj You haven't shared your html code of a full table, so how in the world do you expect us to help you? To get Outlook to work, you either need to make every table cell have a border `<table border="1">` or apply a border to each `td` where you want a border - `td style="mso-border-top-alt: solid #000000 2pt;"`. It's the only thing I have found that works consistently.

Comment: style="border-top: 2px solid #000000;" this helped me to solve one of the issue i.e., HTML rendering was working and same HMTL not working in while rendering in outlook.